# Update operation is not happening in FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlite, fastapi

```py
@app.put("/blog/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def update(id, request: schemas.Blog, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id).update(request)
    db.commit()
    return db
```

Comment: You should avoid using `request` for your schema name, as that usually have a very specific meaning (the `Request` object representing the request). What you get in when you refer to a schema with FastAPI is a Pydantic model, while `update` expects a dict - it can't use a Pydantic model directly as far as I know. So try `.update(request.to_dict())` instead (with a better name than `request`). Returning the `db` object to the user doesn't make sense either, so don't do that - instead return a status message or something similar.

Comment: Also tried using .update(request.to_dict()) but still showing the same error in browser.
 content-length: 21 
 content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
 date: Sat,25 Jun 2022 05:38:37 GMT 
 server: uvicorn 

Here is the error showing in the response header.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer

```py
@app.put("/blog/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def update(id, request: schemas.Blog, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id).update(
        {"title": request.title, "body": request.body}
    )  # **passed each field in a dict**

    db.commit()

    return "Record updated successfully!"
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to your question? If it is an answer, please read [answer] and then [edit] it to clarify. If it is an update, please delete this and edit your question instead.

Comment: As per your request I have edited the same and mentioned that this is the answer.